# PHP - stop foreach at first image shown

Tags: php, wordpress

Im editing a Wordpress plugin, and there's is an option if I set slider for multiple images, it shows all images on post list, but I need only first. How I can stop an exection after first loop?

There's the code

```
<?php if( isset( $postMetaData['_otw_slider_image'] ) && $postMetaData['_otw_slider_image'] ){?>
                    <?php $imagePath = parse_url( $sliderImages[0] );?>
                    <?php if( isset( $sliderImages[0] ) ){?>
                        <?php if( isset( $this->listOptions['image_link'] ) && in_array( $this->listOptions['image_link'], array( 'lightbox' ) ) ){?>
                            <?php $first_shown = false; ?>
                            <?php foreach( $sliderImages as $sImage ){?>
                                <?php $imagePath = parse_url( $sImage );?>
                                <a href="<?php echo $this->otwImageCrop->resize( $imagePath['path'], $imageLightboxWidth, $imageLightboxHeight, $this->imageCrop, $this->imageWhiteSpaces, $this->imageBackground, $imageLightboxFormat )?>" rel="otw_fslide_<?php echo $post->ID?>" title="<?php echo htmlentities( $post->post_title );?>" class="otw_in_slider otw_in_slider_<?php echo intval( $first_shown )?>" >
                                    <?php if( !$first_shown ){?>
                                        <img src="<?php echo $this->otwImageCrop->resize( $imagePath['path'], $this->imageWidth, $this->imageHeight, $this->imageCrop, $this->imageWhiteSpaces, $this->imageBackground, $this->imageFormat )?>" alt="" />
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </a>
                                <?php $first_shown = true;?>
                            <?php }?>
                        <?php }elseif( isset( $this->listOptions['image_link'] ) && in_array( $this->listOptions['image_link'], array( 'single' ) ) ){?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $permaLink?>">
                                <img src="<?php echo $this->otwImageCrop->resize( $imagePath['path'], $this->imageWidth, $this->imageHeight, $this->imageCrop, $this->imageWhiteSpaces, $this->imageBackground, $this->imageFormat )?>" alt="" />
                            </a>
                        <?php }else{ ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo $this->otwImageCrop->resize( $imagePath['path'], $this->imageWidth, $this->imageHeight, $this->imageCrop, $this->imageWhiteSpaces, $this->imageBackground, $this->imageFormat )?>" alt="" />
                        <?php }?>
                    <?php }?>
                <?php }else{?>
                    <div class="otw_portfolio_manager-slider" data-animation="slide">
                        <ul class="slides otw_portfolio_ul_slider">
                            <?php foreach( $sliderImages as $sliderImage ){?>
                                <li>
                                <?php
                                    $imagePath = parse_url($sliderImage);
                                    $sliderImgLink = false;
                                ?>
                                <?php if( isset( $this->listOptions['image_link'] ) && in_array( $this->listOptions['image_link'], array( 'lightbox' ) ) ){ $sliderImgLink = true;?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $sliderImage?>" rel="otw_fslide_<?php echo $post->ID?>" class="otw_portfolio_manager-fancybox-slider" title="<?php echo htmlentities( $post->post_title );?>"></a>
                                <?php }?>
                                <?php if( isset( $this->listOptions['image_link'] ) && in_array( $this->listOptions['image_link'], array( 'single' ) ) ){ $sliderImgLink = true;?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $imgLink?>" title="<?php echo $post->post_title;?>">
                                <?php }?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo $this->otwImageCrop->resize( $imagePath['path'], $this->imageWidth, $this->imageHeight, $this->imageCrop, $this->imageWhiteSpaces, $this->imageBackground, $this->imageFormat )?>" alt="" data-item="media">
                                <?php if( $sliderImgLink ){?>
                                    </a>
                                <?php }?>
                                </li>
                            <?php }?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    <?php }?>
```

Comment: You can stop a foreach loop with `break;`

Comment: Too much `<?PHPs` can you really handle this? plus it is a scope for errors.  Think of doing all your logic and prepare all the variables you need first, then output the HTML document with ready to echo variables, it will make your life much easier

Comment: If you need only the first result, why are you looping at all?

Comment: This is the messiest code I have ever seen.

Comment: @Andreas Thats not mine plugin :) Like I said, Im editing this

Comment: I wouldn't touch that code even with gloves and pliers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its an just example you can do same in your code.

```
$i = 0;

foreach ($largedata as $data) {
   if($i == 0) {
      echo $data->id;
   }
   $i++;
}
```

Hope you will get it from example.

Comment: You don't want to loop through everything if you only want to process the first image.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of needlessly looping through the entire array of `$sliderImages` (assuming here it is an array, rather than an `Iterator`), just grab the first slider image from the array:

```
<?php if (isset( $this->listOptions['image_link'] ) && in_array($this->listOptions['image_link'], array('lightbox' ))) { ?>
    <?php $sliderImages = array_values($sliderImages); ?>
    <?php $sImage = $sliderImages[0]); ?>
    <?php $imagePath = parse_url($sImage); ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->otwImageCrop->resize( $imagePath['path'], $imageLightboxWidth, $imageLightboxHeight, $this->imageCrop, $this->imageWhiteSpaces, $this->imageBackground, $imageLightboxFormat )?>" rel="otw_fslide_<?php echo $post->ID?>" title="<?php echo htmlentities( $post->post_title );?>" class="otw_in_slider otw_in_slider_<?php echo intval( $first_shown )?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->otwImageCrop->resize( $imagePath['path'], $this->imageWidth, $this->imageHeight, $this->imageCrop, $this->imageWhiteSpaces, $this->imageBackground, $this->imageFormat )?>" alt="" />
    </a>
<?php } elseif (isset($this->listOptions['image_link'] ) && in_array($this->listOptions['image_link'], array( 'single' ))) { ?>
    <?php // other logic here?>
<?php } ?>
```

**Note** Using `array_values()` to normalize the keys of `$sliderImages`, so the first element of it can be referenced using `0` as key (not sure what the keys of `$sliderImages` look like).

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php